# In what order should Anne Rice's Vampire Chronicles and Mayfair Witches be read?

Tags: suggested-order, vampire-chronicles, anne-rice

I don't know why it took me so long but I have just started reading the vampire chronicles. I have been looking into the correct reading order and have found vastly different opinions, even from Annerice.com. I have read them in the following order so far but don't know where to go from here:

1. *Interview With a Vampire*
2. *Vampire Lestat*
3. *Queen of the Damned*
4. *Tales of the Body Thief*
5. *Memnoch the Devil*

Some recommend *Vampire Armand* now, some recommend starting the *Mayfair Witches'* books now, and others say to read *Pandora* next

What is the correct reading order?

Comment: We don't usually accept opinion based questions, If you were looking for a specific type of reading order such as "release order" or "chronological order" that would be on-topic

Comment: Thank you. Maybe I should have worded my question differently. I am asking for the correct reading order. I have never encountered a book series with such confusion as to the correct reading order.

Comment: Just my opinion, but I hated the ending of the first Mayfair Witches book so much I'd say don't read them.  Huge, long build-up for the whole book on multiple fronts and then one of the protagonists does an abrupt (and to me, completely unexplained) 180 and everything falls apart in like 5 pages.

Answer (score 1):

1. Interview with the Vampire
2. The Vampire Lestat
3. The Queen of the Damned
4. The Witching Hour
5. STOP!!!

Seriously, they take a sharp nose dive in quality. She started throwing tanties at the idea of being edited and her books suffer badly.

IMHO of course. YMMV.

Answer (score -2):

1. Interview with the Vampire
2. The Vampire Lestat
3. The Queen of the Damned
4. The Tale of the Body Thief
5. The Witching Hour
6. Lasher
7. Taltos
8. Memnoch the Devil
9. Pandora
10. The Vampire Armand
11. Vittorio the Vampire
12. Merrick
13. Blood and Gold
14. Blackwood Farm
15. Blood Canticle
16. Prince Lestat
17. Prince Lestat and the Realms of Atlantis

Is found and explained here: http://www.howtoread.me/vampire-chronicles-reading-order/

Comment: I can choose to follow this order, but there's no reason for me to do so since you haven't explained it at all, which is the most important part of the answer. Can you please explain this order?

Comment: The last answer I found appears to have been the publish order the edited version is from the attached article which gives reasons to read them in this order.

Comment: Providing a link is not enough - if it dies, your answer will lose its value. Please at least summarise here the reasoning for this reading order, and bring back the ordered list I had added (it looks better).